# move_uploaded_file() expects exactly 2 parameters, 3 given

Tags: php

This code is giving me the error

> move_uploaded_file() expects exactly 2 parameters, 3 given

```
if(isset($_POST["upload"])){

    $target="images/".basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $db=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","photos");

    $image=$_FILES['image']['name'];
    $text=$_POST['text'];

    $sql="INSERT INTO images(image,text) VALUES ('$image','$text')";
    mysqli_query($db,$sql); 

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image'],['tmp_name'],$target)){
        $msg="image upload successful";
    }else{
        $msg="there was a problem uploading the image";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code's syntax is wrong:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image'],['tmp_name'],$target)){
                                    --^--
```

Comma is used to separate parameters, so `move_uploaded_file` is called with 3 parameters, 2nd is an array with one string element, "tmp_name". You should remove that comma, since it is not needed to index an array.

---

Also note that you should never put user input directly in an SQL query string, this is dangerous. Read more about SQL injection, and PHP's PDO drivers.